# How to prevent duplicate elements according to one parameter while sorting for another parameter, Data Structures, Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, sorting, kotlin, data-structures, duplicates

Assume a `class Student` with parameters `name`, `grade` and `ID`:

```
class Student (name: String, grade: String, ID: String) {  
    var _studentID = ID
    var _studentName = name
    var _studentGrade = grade

    //override hashCode(), equals(), compareTo() etc
}
```

How to prevent duplicate entries according to `ID`, while sorting them -automatically if possible- according to `name`?

It is not impossible to use an `ArrayList` inside a `for` loop to check for duplicates then use `sortBy` function. This approach allows me to give a feedback to the user too. However, there might be a better algorithm or Data Structure (i.e. HashSet, TreeMap etc.) for the job. What do you recommend?

P.S. I also tried TreeSet. But somehow the TreeSet allowed instances with similar IDs into the set occasionally (say 1 in 5 successive tries). Do you have an idea how this happened? Can it be due to different threads operating on the same data, or due to inconsistent `equals()` and `compareTo()` methods (`equals()` was overridden for `ID` and `compareTo()` was overridden according to `name`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html) would be best choice if you want to maintain a `sorted data set`. because it provides guaranteed `log(n)` time cost for the basic operations (add, remove and contains).

In order to use it you will either have to define `natural ordering` for your class by implementing [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html), or you will have to provide a `comparator`.

While implementing the [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html) for TreeSet you must note one thing, from `TreeSet` and `Comparable` docs

> Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit
>   comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals if it is to
>   correctly implement the Set interface
>
> ***The natural ordering for a class C is said to be consistent with
>   equals if and only if e1.compareTo(e2) == 0 has the same boolean value
>   as e1.equals(e2)***

Now to implement `Comparable` in a way which is consistent with above statement, you would do the following.

```
class Student (name: String, grade: String, ID: String): Comparable<Student>{
    var studentID = ID
    var studentName = name
    var studentGrade = grade

    // Use the default equals generated by your IDE, but only take into accout ID field
    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false
        other as Student
        if (studentID != other.studentID) return false
        return true
    }

    // Whenever you override equals, you also need to override hashCode
    override fun hashCode() = studentID.hashCode()

    // Define natural ordering
    override fun compareTo(other: Student): Int {
        if(equals(other)) return 0
        var nameComparison = studentName.compareTo(other.studentName)
        return when(nameComparison){
            // If two objects are equal when compared by name then we sort them by id
            0 -> studentID.compareTo(other.studentID)
            else -> nameComparison
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. `if (equals(other))` is a nice trick. In my code it was `if (studentID == other.studentID) return 0`. Maybe this was the reason of inconsistency. `when()` part is also well thought. Instead of `when()` I had written `else {return (studentName.compareTo(other.studentName))`. Kotlin does not like `return` statements inside `if` or `when`. Do you know the reason?

Comment: Btw, I ended up using an ArrayList, checking similar elements inside a `for` loop. This way I can detect the already existing element and give feedback to the user and return information about it. As a side note for the novice readers, there are other consistency requirements for TreeSets than mentioned in the answer (i.e. if `e1.compareTo(e2) = 0 ---> e2.compareTo(e1) = 0` or `sign(e1.compareTo(e2)) = -sign(e2.compareTo(e1))` etc.)

Comment: You can do the same with TreeSet, read the docs for add method, it returns a boolean indicating if the set already contain the specified element. You can also use contains. these are going to be very fast compared to finding an element in ArrayList

Comment: Jup but I need to make the comparison due to ID only. Is there a usage like `if (studentSet.contains(newStudent.studentID)) ` ? Also, looks like TreeSet does not use indexing. How do I specifiy the studentName of the corresponding studentID without an index?